# Пушкин и  Парни

Tags: литература

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ответ на вопрос! Какие русско-французские традиции в русск.лит-ре  связывает Пушкина и Парни? Что у них общего?

Comment: "Пушкин и парни" - это надо запомнить! Звучит даже круче, чем "Пушкин и компания"!

Answer (score 1):

Русско-французские традиции - вольтерьянство, просветительство,соединение высокой элегии с революционным рационализмом.

Общее с Парни: искренность чувств, элегичность; лёгкий стих; в раннем творчестве эпикурейские и  анакреонтические мотивы(Наслаждение жизнью, любовь, вино, дружеское общение, независимость, пусть сопровождаемая «бедностью» и «умеренностью»).

Общее - ( в  лицейских стихах Пушкина) если не антирелигиозные, то антипоповские ноты. В стихотворении «К другу стихотворцу», написанном пятнадцатилетним поэтом, приводится история о пьяном священнике, в которой не видно во всяком случае пиэтета к церковному культу и его служителям. В стихотворении «Городок» есть такие строки:

Но, боже, виноват!

Я каюсь пред тобою,

Служителей твоих,

Попов я городских

Боюсь, боюсь беседы

И свадебны обеды

Затем лишь не терплю,

Что сельских иереев,

Как папа иудеев,

Я вовсе не люблю.

Прошло немного лет, и Пушкин принужден был сознаться:

Я знаю: нежного Парни

Перо не в моде в наши дни.

Французское влияние: мотивы «свободы», независимости в смысле личном(от Парни) соединяются у Пушкина с мотивами свободы в смысле политическом(вольтерьянство). Стихотворение «Деревня» начинается прославлением личной свободы, «праздности вольной». От этих мотивов совершается переход к свободе общественной: «Но мысль ужасная здесь душу омрачает» и т. д. Кончается стихотворение прямыми словами о «прекрасной заре свободы просвещенной». Личное и общественное связаны здесь в духе философии «естественного права».

Внутренняя свобода неразлучна с «просвещением» и «законом». «Учися в истине блаженство находить, свободною душой закон боготворить» говорит Пушкин в «Деревне». Не случаен в конце стихотворения и эпитет «свободы» — «просвещенная». В «Вольности» он пишет: «Везде неправедная власть, в сгущенной мгле предрассуждений воссела». И дальше, обращаясь к «владыкам»: «стоите выше вы народа, но вечный выше вас закон». «Сгущенная мгла предрассуждений» включала в себя для Пушкина и религиозные предрассудки. Об этом говорят его эпиграммы против носителей религиозного мракобесия того времени.

Философия наслаждения(эпикурейство) мотивировалась требованиями «разума», бренностью жизни, мимолетностью юности.
 «Вакхическая песня» (1825 г.) начинается прославлением любви и вина.
Да здравствуют нежные девы

И юные жены, любившие нас!

Полнее стакан наливайте!

На звонкое дно

В густое вино

Заветные кольца бросайте!

Но тем знаменательнее дальнейшие строки.

Подымем стаканы, содвинем их разом!

Да здравствуют музы, да здравствует разум!

Ты, солнце святое, гори!

Как эта лампада бледнеет

Пред ясным восходом зари,

Так ложная мудрость мерцает и тлеет

Пред солнцем бессмертным ума.

Да здравствует солнце, да скроется тьма!

Здесь «ложная мудрость» была вовсе не поэтической фразой, а вполне реальной враждебной силой. И против нее рука об руку ополчаются разум, музы, эротика и вино. А призыв «да здравствует разум!» настолько явно напрашивался на политическое истолкование, что Герцен поставил его на своей «Полярной Звезде».
«Эпикуреизм» был не чем-то внешним, он был органическою частью целостного идейного комплекса. Это была та форма, в которой становился дворянский либерализм

Answer (score 0):

Вообще про Пушкина и Парни написано довольно много.

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8,_%D0%AD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82

Но вот так, как вопрос поставлен, какие *традиции*, да еще *русско-французские*...
Пушкин элегий (в истинном по крайней мере понимания слова) не писал, вот единственное, кажется, исключение, да и то больше - по названию.
http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/texts/push17/vol01/y012216-.htm

он много их много переводил, из Парни - в т.ч.

Посмотрите у Эткинда, может чего и найдете прямо по теме.
http://lib.ru/POEZIQ/PARNI/parni.txt

(+)
Слушайте, а может быть речь идет о вольнодумстве? Парни был известным вольтерьянцем, про Пушкина даже упоминать излишне...